# How to increase speed of Node.js app using Mysql database in online gaming

Tags: mysql, node.js, flutter, myisam

I'm building an online multi platform game, something like Ludo game but it takes 10 players to play about 30 to 60 minutes. Lets assume every 10 players in my Database are a row at Lobby table.

So when I have 10 rows at lobby table, it means 100 users are online.

the Back-end server is a Node.js that uses web socket protocol.

for now I'm about to release the game, But I'm trying to see some scaling of long term growing number of users.

In node.js server I have implemented an Interval every 1 second to read and change data on database.

if I use Innodb table Engine things are good until I have about 500 rows, after that the 1 second interval executes longer... and it really uses so much of my pc NVME ssd (more than 70%) and very little usage of memory or CPU.

if I use Issam table Engine things are good about 3000 rows and then it executes longer... however I have no idea in real situation with real users if it locks or not, and it also is not using so much of resources and no ssd usage at all which is odd comparing to innodb.

Now I have this questions:

1- Is there any memory or CPU limitations on Node.js that I can Increase to perform better?

2-Is there any  limitations on MySQL or table engines that I can Increase to perform better?

3- I'm Using typeorm so I may use other databases other than MySQL like MariaDB or PostgreSQL ,... do you recommend them to perform better?

4- Right now I'm using only one table called lobby that has more than 30 columns and contains 6000 rows (60,000 online users) which is not performing good (More than 1 second executes), What can I do to make it better ? and it's size is only 1.5 Mb.

5- And the most important question, How do google or Instagram and big companies handle their big multi read write databases?? what am I missing? Is there some magical codes ? What I can not understand is that even my PC Cpu and memory do not engaged that much, Just like 10 to 20% of CPU and about 1Gb of ram used by the application and my whole 6000 rows is just 1.5Mb .

So far I tried increasing innodb buffer size, merging some quires together and ...

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if a query on 3000 rows took longer than a 1 second! That dataset is very small. But if you want notification service, then you are better off with an in-memory database (like redis) or a message queue (like rabbitMQ) as mysql does not have any notification built into it

Comment: Thanks, I checked redis and rabbitMQ and unfortunately TypeOrm is not supporting them... I'm limited to use MySQL and above mentioned databases. I'm trying to make node.js or MySQL use more CPU maybe that helps

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Show us a few queries.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.  The numbers sound like a "tiny" database.  Perhaps indexes are missing.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting, I guess I'm figuring out what was the problem... I had made a For loop for my game in node.js, And for example for 6000 lobby entries(ROWS), It was changing some column data like Timer and passes time every 1 seconds. So it was going to update all 6000 rows from my Node application. What I was missing was the big time and resource consuming this task was. right now I'm trying to shift the For loop to MYSQL built-in Event So in my node.js App I'm only going to change data on database for received data from user. I tested with 20,000 Rows and it's working perfect

Comment: I would surly update in after I made this changes, right now except MySQL event handler I'm out of any Idea... Because this is an Online game server and I need to have a global timer for every lobby and check for changes... I need to use some Cron job to be easy and fast and also scalable , So any suggestion would be perfect Thank you all